# Pass a dictionary of items to a method as individual parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a method which looks like this:

```
def order_by(*args):
    print list(args)
```

Is there a way I could pass a list of three items and have each item in the list passed as an individual parameters?

```
params = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

would equate to

```
order_by('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*arguments` syntax can be used for *calling* functions too, provided `params` is an iterable:

```
order_by(*params)
```

See the [calls syntax specification](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls).

For an actual dictionary, use the `**kwargs` syntax:

```
params = dict(a='a', b='b', c='c')
somemethod(**params)
```

where `somemethod` accepts `a`, `b` and `c` arguments or has a `**kw` catch-all argument. Note that `**params` does *not* work if all your function defines is a `*args` positional argument catch-all.

Comment: @MarkL: I've corrected your question, you were talking about lists, not dictionaries, if my answer was correct. :-)

Answer (score -3):

Use the Python built-in `apply`:

```
apply(order_by, params)
```

Comment: From the [`apply` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#apply): *Deprecated since version 2.3: Use the extended call syntax with `*args` and `**keywords` instead.* The function has been removed from Python 3.